# Proper way of making my python module available to the mlflow during mlflow models build-docker

Tags: python, data-science, mlflow, mlops

I am trying to build a docker image that I could host with an endpoint of my model and have experienced issues on how to make my code available during the build so that the image would later run and serve the model.

I am trying a model which is a sklearn type of classifier, however it is wrapped in my modified version of `sklearn.Pipeline` class, let's call it a `BypassablePipeline`. The model trains fine, I am logging it into the mlflow tracking server with, I am also able to pull it again and execute it locally. This is how I log the model:

```
   model_info = mlflow.sklearn.log_model(model,
                                     artifact_path='model',
                                     registered_model_name=model_registry_name,
                                     signature=model_signature, 
                                     pip_requirements=my_pip_requirements)
```

I have the `BypassablePipeline` in `mymodule` and installed it in development mode, my `requirements.txt` file example, omitting other packages for simplicity sake:

```
scikit_learn==1.2.0
mlflow==2.1.1
-e .
```

. is where I locally have the `setup.py` for my `mymodule` and installs fine. When I execute `pip list` this is what I am getting:

```
scikit_learn 1.2.0
mlflow       2.1.1
mymodule     0.0.1 /home/my_user/my_repo/
```

plus it is working locally.

These requirements are passed as `my_pip_requirements` to the `log_model` above. Also, I am creating the local environment using `pyenv`. Next, I am activating the environment and run:
`mlflow models build-docker -m "path_to_model" --enable-mlserver -n "image_name" --env-manager=virtualenv`
The model server build runs fine. When I later try to test if the server stands up using:
`docker run "image_name"`
This where problems starts to occur and I am getting an error, namely:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'`

Clearly the module although present in my env, is not properly transferred during build time. So far I have tried the following:

1. Prior to the docker build using the above command I am creating a fresh environment and building a wheel package out of `mymodule` then replacing the `-e .` line with the path to the wheel. Relogged the model again to have proper the `my_pip_requirements` and the error is still there.
2. Tried `local` instead of `virtualenv` but then it also omits much more (for instance python version) which becomes a warning but error is still there.
3. Wrapped the model with `PythonModel` per examples in mlflow repo:

```
class PyfuncModelWrapper(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):
    def load_context(self, context):
        self.model = mlflow.sklearn.load_model(context.artifacts['original_model_path'])
        
    def predict(self, context, model_input, params: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None):
        return self.model.predict(model_input)
```

Can you point me in the right direction here? What have worked for you? Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Michal

**Update 9/6/2023**
Just not to leave this question hanging and for anyone who looked for solution like me.

I did not identify why model does not find the module while I am building a package out of it and installing in the env, that I am building the docker image from, using the commands above. However, I made the model working using `PyfuncModelWrapper(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel)`. I had to wrap the model in this wrapper using `mlflow` docs (need `load_context` and `predict` methods). Then `mlflow.pyfunc.log_model` has a `code_path` argument where I could pass a `list` of modules or folders with the modules (namely a package). When model is logged it copies the code as an artifact which I think is a less elegant solution, but it works. The code is carried over the docker image with served model and while starting it I no longer get the error.

Hope this work around could help someone. I am registering both models, the original `sklearn` flavor and the wrapped one, note that `model_info` is from the snippet earlier.

```
mlflow.pyfunc.log_model(
                artifact_path='pyfunc_model',
                code_path=['./my_package/'],
                artifacts={'original_model_path': model_info.model_uri},
                python_model=PyfuncModelWrapper(),
                signature=model_signature,
                pip_requirements=my_pip_requirements,
                await_registration_for=100,
                registered_model_name=model_registry_name,
            )
```